# MediaElement в WinRT

Tags: c#, windows, winrt, windows-8

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой:
Есть `WinRT` приложение, в нем есть элемент класса `MediaElement`.
Нужно в нем по нажатию некой кнопки воспроизводить видео, которое не является файлом проекта.

Я это делаю так:
Пусть `MediaElement me;`

```
me.Source = new Uri(@"c:\1.mp4");
me.Play();
```

Такой код без проблем работает в `WPF`, однако в `WinRT` видео не воспроизводится. В чем проблема? Что я упустил? Может надо дополнительно поставить какие-то свойства `MediaElement'а`?

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, WinRT не даст вам использовать абсолютные пути.

Делайте, как [описано в MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx).

Comment: кстати подскажите это справедливо ТОЛЬКО для Store приложений? Или и для десктопных тоже не пустит?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, только для Store. Десктопные приложения имеют полный доступ (в рамках прав текущего пользователя, конечно).

Comment: Вы можете, кстати, попробовать [`FileOpenPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx).